# How can I make an inline HTML style override a CSS style?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am passing a value into an Angular Material Table to set the row color to black, but it keeps getting overridden by my css style sheet (which sets the column to blue)? I thought the inline style took precedence, what am I doing wrong here?

I expected this to take precedence (setting the row value to gray):

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': row.color}"></mat-row>
```

over this css (which sets an individual column to blue and leaves all others gray):

```
.mat-column-paios, .mat-column-papc, .mat-column-pd, .mat-column-appfamily-pa,
.mat-column-appfamily-pd, .mat-column-eis, .mat-column-appfamily-eis {
    background-color: #26428b; /*#3d8299; blue*/
    color: white;
    flex: 0 0 7%;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<mat-table class="lessons-table mat-elevation-z8 overflow-x-auto" [dataSource]="serverLicenseDS" matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="paios">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>PAIOS</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let e">{{e.paios}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky:true"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': row.color}"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

My CSS:

```
.overflow-x-auto {
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.mat-column-select {
    overflow: initial;
}

.example-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 300px;
}

.example-header {
    min-height: 64px;
    padding: 8px 24px 0;
}

.mat-column-sumName {
    background-color: black; /*#3d8299; blue*/
    color: white;
    flex: 0 0 16%;
}

.mat-column-paios, .mat-column-papc, .mat-column-pd, .mat-column-appfamily-pa,
.mat-column-appfamily-pd, .mat-column-eis, .mat-column-appfamily-eis {
    background-color: #26428b; /*#3d8299; blue*/
    color: white;
    flex: 0 0 7%;
}

.mat-column-paplus, .mat-column-pd, .mat-column-dropoff,
 .mat-column-appfamily-dropoff, .mat-column-appfamily-paplus {
    background-color: #666665; /* #3d993d green*/
    color: white;
    flex: 0 0 7%;
}
```

Comment: have u tried `/deep` ? Give it a try or if possible please create a demo example on stackblitz.com & update question with some image file of expected result. I'll try to fix that. Let me know

Comment: What does your rendered HTML look like?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below css to your stylesheet

```
.row-color {
    background-color: black;
 }
```

And that class to `mat-tag` in html like this `<mat-row [ngClass]=('row-color')></mat-row>`